# Question about public key encryption

Tags: windows, linux, encryption, public-key-encryption

Let's say for example, there is a client and a server. They have both exchanged public keys with each other. Now how is public key encryption applied when downloading the data from the server to the client?

Comment: This is not strictly a programming question as they belong here, but Vladislav gave you a nice short answer. The only thing I would add is that when signing comes in (not just encryption) the public key is used to prove that a certain piece of information was indeed signed by the other party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

digital certificates are used in that case which carries users public key in an encrypted form. A server has it's own certificate and a client also has one which are then matched before the downloading starts.

Comment: The public key in a certificate is *not* in an encrypted form.

Answer (score 3):

The server encrypts with it's **private** key and this data can be decrypted with the **public** key (and vice-versa). The numbers and the algorithm are made like this - they don't need to know each others' private keys.

One of the simpler algorithms is called RSA, you can find more on how it works on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA). You'll need some maths, but nothing very complicated there.

For performance reasons, public key cryptography is used only for transmitting a normal, symmetric key.